# Is it possible to wrap .NET libraries with MAUI and compile them to native libraries (AAR,XCFramework)?

Tags: android, maui

I have three .dll written in .NET. I would like to use these libraries in native Android/iOS projects (actually it's Flutter). The idea was to build a "native" wrapper around these libs and compile to an `.aar` and `Framework` for iOS. However, in the Maui documentation I only read about writing a binding layer to use those libraries in a Maui project. But, I need it the other way round.

Is this even possible? Does anyone have a starting point for me?

Comment: No, this is not possible

Comment: You can host them locally, and make calls on localhost. I know that it is not the same, but if they are so specific and reuse is that important, this is a way to get the job done.

Comment: @H.A.H.: Interesting idea. Unfortunately, I've never done something like that before and have no idea to to host a dll locally on a mobile device. Do you have an article, search term, or maybe a sample project showing the concept?

Comment: @ASP you are not hosting a dll. You are hosing a service with API calls. The service is written using MAUI, and when you make a web request, a method in the dll is executed, and you get back your result as response. I was involved indirectly years ago in similar project. A printer service running on Android device (that was multiplatform written with C# code, Mono)  and this was instead of providing a platform specific JAR file. You would setup this Server to host on port, and connect to that port from Android app. And then just make API calls.